# Cannot PUSH recent commits to Github that have been pushed to Bitbucket

Tags: xcode, git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I have two remote repositories. One is private (Bitbucket) and the other public (Github). I had been pushing changes to Bitbucket using Github app and then pushing the same commit to Github repo using Xcode. However, recently I have been unable to PUSH the commits to Github and using SourceTree I get this error message:

```
This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/pre-push.
```

This is how it looks from within SourceTree:

[image]

How can I get my Github repo to accept the most recent commits?

Answer (score 4):

You have a pre-push hook which is telling you that you have git-lfs (large file support) enabled for this repository, but that it can't find the git-lfs program on your computer. The solution is to either remove the hook (which is located in `.git/hooks/pre-push`, as the error message says), or to fix your `PATH` so that it can find the git-lfs program.

Comment: Ok. I am new to this issue. How would I go about fixing my path? Thanks.

Comment: `PATH` is an environment variable containing a list of search directories which your shell uses to find the programs you run. The way you change it depends on what OS you're using, and a few other details, but most OSes use the bash shell. If you're using the bash shell, just edit your ~/.bashrc script. There are plenty of places to find out all the details that won't fit into a comment.

Comment: I removed the .git/hooks/pre-push. Now i can upload to github again. Why did github start to add these ".git/hooks/pre-push" files though? I have to delete these files every time now? When I use Github desktop for mac. There is no problem. When i use the command line it doesnt work. unless i delete the mentioned file. Shouldnt such a thing be opt in?

Comment: Maybe GitHub's desktop application adds it for you, now that GitHub supports LFS. The ordinary git command-line client certainly doesn't, and the GitHub webpage couldn't (hooks aren't downloaded from the server). I've never used GitHub's specialized clients, so you'll have to figure that out for yourself. Perhaps there's something in the settings, or a way to configure each repository within it.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been enough to say that the .git directory is in the original local directory of your repository and you probably need a program like TextWrangler or similar, that shows the hidden files starting with a dot, to be able to see it and delete it by moving it to the trash (right click mouse). It took me one hour to figure out this. I hope no one else have to waste that time.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the instructions for removing the pre-push file using Mac Terminal:**
First: `cd` to the directory that is your local repository for your project. (The main folder that holds .xcodeproj and other files) The .git file is hidden but you can still access it by typing `cd .git/hooks` in terminal. If you type `ls` in terminal to view all files within the current directory, you'll notice the **pre-push** file. Type `rm pre-push` to remove the file. You should now be able to push to your remote repository. Just be sure to `cd ..` back a few times to your local directory for your project. Simple as that.